# Mitigate Client Dom Stored Xss from Jquery append method flagged by Checkmarx

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss, checkmarx, dompurify

For my Project I have the Jquery 2.2.0 version and recently The Checkmarx scan is added for the project.

I am trying to find out a solution for "Client DOM Stored XSS" error. I have used the DomPurify library for the html sanitization before appending the html to the node but no luck! Any suggestions how Checkmarx flags this or any recommended/accepted library for "html sanitization" by checkmarx would be great. Below is the code snippet.

> The application's function embeds untrusted data in the generated output with append, at line 241 of
> Sample.js. This untrusted data is embedded straight into the output without proper sanitization or
> encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the output.

```js
....
241. success: function (data) {
//The htmlStr is formed from the data returned by ajax call. There are some concatenation and simple business logic before its added to a DOM.
....
256.
jQuery(row).find('.MyClass').append(DOMPurify.sanitize(htmlStr, { SAFE_FOR_JQUERY: true }));
```

Its not recognizing DOMPurify.sanitize. Also tried with $.parseHTML()

Comment: Please indicate your Checkmarx version and hotfix.  DOMPurify may need to be added via query tuning depending on the version you're using.

Comment: @srikant HAve you got any solution for this ? i am also facing same issue.

Comment: Yes @santoshe61 - Its a weird solution though. use a different variable ex: JQ = jQuery.noConflict()... then use JQ